Negativity of a function with differential inequality as condition
The question comes from Tao's book on dispersive PDE. In the appendix B, he shows uniqueness of ground state. In the second part of lemma B.10, he proves that
$$\partial_t^2 u_y(t) + \frac{d-1}{t} \partial_t u_y(t) < 0, $$
where $u_y(t)$ is strictly decreasing for all $t > 0$, with $u_y(0) = y > 0$ and $\partial_t u_y(0) = 0$. He says that one can use a comparison principle for ODE to get that $u_y$ is negative. So I thought that I can prove $u_y < \partial_t u_y < 0$. How can I do that?
